# How to mask part of an email address in a plain text string to hide user details

Tags: python

Given an text string which ends with an email address, how do I mask:

1. All but the first letter of the email ID
2. Part of the domain name

Sample Input:

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. china@youwan.com"
```

Expected Result:

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. cxxxx@xxxxx.com"
```

Comment: `regex` and `str.replace`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Identify the email address in the data.

```
>>> input_text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. china@youwan.com"
>>> body, email_id = input_text.rsplit(' ', 1)
>>> email_id
'china@youwan.com'
```

2. Replace the email address with `x`.

```
>>> import re
>>> email_split = re.split('@|.', email_id)
>>> email_split
['china','youwan','com']

>>> username, domain_front, *domain_back_list = email_split
>>> username_masked = username[0]+'x'*(len(username)-1)
>>> domain_front_masked = 'x'*len(domain_front)
>>> domain_back = '.'.join(domain_back_list)
>>> email_masked = '{}@{}.{}'.format(username_masked, domain_front_masked, domain_back)
>>> email_masked
'cxxxx@xxxxx.com'
```

3. Join the masked email address back with the original text string:

```
>>> result = '{} {}'.format(body, email_masked)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but the code display only hashed data from a string ,not showing complete string .. Suppose , i have a string like the country is becoming more sustainable to invite the companies @gmail.com .Here I have to display entire string include hashed email id .

Comment: It will help greatly if you can provide some examples and what is the expected result. The question is not very clear.

Comment: For Example :  China is inviting globally  for investments in their country among all the sectors .for details please reach us at  china@youwan.com .                            
Expected Result  as China is inviting globally  for investments in their country among all the sectors .for details please reach us at  xxxxx@xxxxx.com

Comment: I want to mask email address like cxxxx@xxxxx.com.is it possible to show

Comment: You might want to try this, to keep the first letter of the username and domain name, and mask the rest: `email_masked_front = '@'.join([i[0]+'x'*(len(i)-1) for i in email_split[:2]])`

Comment: I want to have first letter of username and do not want to show the  first letter of the domain name ...I want to display like  this cxxxx@xxxxx.com.

Comment: Ok, the updated code should work now. i've broken down the email into 3 parts, namely the `username`, `domain_front` and `domain_back`.

Comment: at this command domain_back = '.'join(domain_back_list) ,it is not displaying domain back list as .com.I tried it to get  but no luck .can you please check it .

Comment: Missing a dot just now.